# Prometheus metric for uploaded file sizes

Tags: prometheus, grafana, bucket, promql

I'm new to Grafana and Prometheus and I'm having trouble showing the sizes of uploaded files.

I want to show something like below in Grafana (in order to spot what file sizes are uploaded the most)

```
 |
 |   |       .
 |   |   |   |
-------------------------
1MB 2MB 3MB 4MB ..
```

I've created this Histogram below

```
uploaded_file_sizes = Summary(
    'uploaded_file_sizes',
    'Uploaded file size in bytes',
    buckets=(
        10000,    #   10KB
        100000,   #   100KB
        500000,   #   500KB
        1000000,  #   1MB
        1500000,  #   1.5MB
        2000000,  #   2MB
        2500000,  #   2.5MB
        3000000,  #   3MB
        3500000,  #   3.5MB
        4000000,  #   4MB
        4500000,  #   4.5MB
        5000000,  #   5MB
        10000000,  #   10MB
        15000000,  #   15MB
        20000000,  #   20MB
        25000000,  #   25MB
        30000000,  #   30MB
        35000000,  #   35MB
        40000000,  #   40MB
        45000000,  #   45MB
        50000000,  #   50MB
    ),
)
```

That's fine and it gives the below data at the metrics endpoint

```
# HELP uploaded_file_sizes Uploaded file size in bytes
# TYPE uploaded_file_sizes histogram
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="10000.0"} 0.0
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="100000.0"} 0.0
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="500000.0"} 0.0
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="1e+06"} 2.0
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="1.5e+06"} 3.0
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="2e+06"} 3.0
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="2.5e+06"} 3.0
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="3e+06"} 3.0
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="3.5e+06"} 3.0
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="4e+06"} 3.0
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="4.5e+06"} 3.0
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="5e+06"} 3.0
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="1e+07"} 3.0
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="1.5e+07"} 3.0
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="2e+07"} 3.0
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="2.5e+07"} 3.0
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="3e+07"} 3.0
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="3.5e+07"} 3.0
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="4e+07"} 3.0
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="4.5e+07"} 3.0
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="5e+07"} 3.0
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="+Inf"} 3.0
uploaded_file_sizes_count 3.0
uploaded_file_sizes_sum 2.848696e+06
```

At this point I am lost at how to show something like below in Grafana. The confusing part is that whatever I try, I end up getting a graph with weird count numbers so I'm sure I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The secret is to set the ranges for your buckets instead of actual values. E.g. instead of 1MB bucket for a 1MB bar in the graph, set two buckets of 0.5MB and 1.5MB to act as the range.

Example

```py
uploaded_file_sizes = Summary(
    'uploaded_file_sizes',
    'Uploaded file size in bytes',
    buckets=(
        500000,  # 500KB
        1500000, # 1.5MB
        2000000, # 2.5MB
    )
)
```

From that we will create 4 bars based on the **ranges**; <1MB, 1MB (files in range 0.5-1.5MB), 1MB (range 0.5-1.5MB), 2MB (range 1.5-2.5MB), 3MB+ (range 2.5-infMB).

Then to beat the cumulative nature of the histogram we need in each query, to calculate the **rate of change** from one bucket to another.

```
# Query 1: <1MB
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="500000.0"}

# Query 2: 1MB
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="1.5e+06"} - ignoring(le)
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="500000.0"}

# Query 3: 2MB
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="2.5e+06"} - ignoring(le)
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="1.5e+06"}

# Query 4: 3MB+
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="+Inf"} - ignoring(le)
uploaded_file_sizes_bucket{le="2.5e+06"}
```